# Editor for Modelica Language with Syntax highlighting and Code completion?

Tags: text-editor

I think OpenModelica has a very bad editor. Specially when you want to edit the code and it is not complete, OpenModelica doesn't allow saving! I usually have to use a different editor to write the code incrementally and open it in OpenModelica for simulation.

What is the best editor (including plugins) for Modelica Language? Features I want to have are:

- Syntax highlighting
- Auto Code Completion
- Cross Platform
- Open Source

I would appreciate if you could share your experience.

Comment: I can suggest to make an plugin for CudaText (cross-platform, open source) and its Python API. It has Modelica lexer. Current editor SimForge is in Java, it's not easy to change.

Comment: @RProgram how about the existing plugins for Vim or Atom?

Comment: It's good alternative, but CudaText is faster than Atom.

Answer (score 1):

You may try Notepad++ in Windows.
User-defined language file for Modelica language shall be downloaded from https://gist.github.com/dietmarw/3346903.
Although it is not perfect, it is a good starting point and can be further developed if required.